# Manual tab completions in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I would like `nm[TAB]` to expand to `node_modules` in zsh. Is this possible? How can it be done?

Ideally, it wouldn't be triggered if there is another completion available, such as an already existing `nm` directory, and only trigger if there is a `node_modules` folder that exists, and complete if it is a part of a path, such as `cd nm/mo[TAB]` -> `cd node_modules/moment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short & sweet answer

Try my [`zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete). It configures Zsh's completion system to do what you're asking for out of the box, plus lots of other useful features.

## Longer, DIY answer

To get fuzzy completion in Zsh, add this to your `.zshrc`:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:|?=**'
```

What this does is tell the completion system to allow any number of characters added anywhere to the string you've typed.

Next, to get the thing you want with directories, add this:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*' accept-exact-dirs true
zstyle ':completion:*' list-suffixes true
```

- `accept-exact-dirs` makes it so that when you have two dirs `nm` and `node_modules` and you type `nm`, it will *never* try to complete it to the latter.
- `list-suffixes` tells it to try to complete every partial directory name in the path you've entered and not just the first one.

To get the `accept-exact-dirs`-style behavior also for all other completions, add this:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*' accept-exact true
```

More info can be found here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles

Comment: Asked 6 years ago and answered beautifully! thanks! Unfortunately, your plugin has some significant jank on my setup, so i disabled it for now. I'll comment in your repo.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to your comments. 

Comment: For the matcher-list style, `'l:?||_=*'` is perhaps closer to what the question actually asks for. Assuming the underscore is to be taken as significant in the completion trial candidates.